# Fourier analysis on linear spaces and general smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, fourier-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, fourier-transform

Problem: Suppose we want to perform Fourier transform on a smooth function that is defined on an $m$-dimensional smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($1 \le m \le n-1$) i.e., we wish to obtain $\mathcal{F}f$ for $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $dim(M) = m$. I have only learned about Fourier analysis for functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not on manifolds. How do we define the Fourier transform here? By using coordinate functions $\{\phi_i\}$ and computing $\mathcal{F} \phi_i f \phi_i^{-1}$? Can we do this for functions defined on a **hyperplane** in $\mathbb{R}^n$? What about general manifolds?

This question is related to a previous question of mine: [A property of the x-ray transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899139/a-property-of-the-x-ray-transform) (see the answer to the question)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13902/does-a-fourier-transformation-on-a-pseudo-riemannian-manifold-make-sense

Comment: The Fourier transform can be [generalized to groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Generalizations), but not to arbitrary manifolds as far as I know. For hyperplanes, you can just use any isometry to $\mathbb R^m$ and apply the Fourier transform there.